# Flutter web get loading error after deployed on Jenkins

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When deploying to Jenkins and then accessing the website, it was just loading.
Chrome console:

- "Refused to execute script from 'https://*******.com/web_entrypoint.dart.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."
  -"Uncaught Error: Script error for "web_entrypoint.dart", needed by: main_module.bootstrap".
  This is code index.html
  /*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="taskdino_platform">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/ic_launcher.png">
  <!-- Croppie -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.css" />
  <script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exif-js/2.3.0/exif.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/croppie/2.6.5/croppie.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="ic_launcher.png"/>

  <title>Taskdino</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAAmDUD2ziWCN5Q1uIbk7fRKnJQWpRQqeE"></script>
  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loading"></div>
<script>
         window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
           var loading = document.querySelector('#loading');
           loading.textContent = "Loading entrypoint...";
           _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
             serviceWorker: {
               serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
             }
           }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
             loading.textContent = "Initializing engine...";
             return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
           }).then(function(appRunner) {
             loading.textContent = "Running app...";
             return appRunner.runApp();
           });
         });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

/*

Please help!
Much obliged.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The right answer can be found in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/75335747/13085174